# What’s the purpose of the metal sponges around the CPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, logicboard

While repasting my Retina late 2013 MacBook Pro I noticed one of the spongy metal disks around the CPU partially broke.

What’s the purpose of these?

I reassembled the machine and it seems to work fine, but I’m wondering what problems will it have with one of these items missing.

TIA,
Edoardo

[image: logic board close-up]

Comment: Looks like a ground connector - did they go to the case or ground plane at all on the top / bottom of them? (i.e. other bit not shown) The only other use of a packer I've heard about is a 'fix' for iffy GPU connections where as the case forces the chip down onto the solder beads under it!

Comment: They **may be** standoffs for the heatsink (https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/heatsink-screw-standoff-popped-off-the-board.1989076/)

Comment: The other side rests against the heat pipe, where its protective plastic sheath is cut to reveal the underlying copper. So they might be grounding connectors for the heat pile and radiator assembly